# Can not open socket in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, sockets, xmpp, openfire, agsxmpp

i am writing a C# program for communicate with `open fire` by `XMPP` protocol using `agsXMPP` .

for start i use `MiniClient` from `ags group` and run it. with some simple modifications this program run and connect correctly.

But when i change Target Framework from `.Net 2.0` to `.Net 4.5.1` or `.Net 4.5` program run but when i want to connect get socket error `No such host is known`.

for `jid` i am enter `test@192.168.1.7` and it connect on `.Net 2.0` but got error in `.Net 4.5`.

i have some libraries that i must use `.Net 4.5` and up.

how i can fix this problem?

Comment: You could write a library in .NET 2.0 just for the connection and communication part and then include it in your main application.

Comment: Thanks for interesting solution.